# Awk multiple file manipulation

Tags: shell, awk

Ok, let's try this again.

How can I open multiple files within AWK, and then just print them all to standard output?  The following prints only the first line of each file.

```
BEGIN {
}
{
$file = $1;
(getline < $file)
print $0;
}

awk -f program.awk myindex
```

myindex is a list of files

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

an example of file1

```
rigrg
gdfgbt
rfghrth
thfg
bhtd
ht
hthrtjhrth
rtg
rthhrthrt
```

Comment: if you posted the 1st file contents and fragments from the 2nd and 3rd file, then, the desired output for that input - it will increase your chances to obtain quick answer

Comment: The manipulation of the contents of the file isn't so important so much as the ability to open the files in the first place, but I can put together examples.

Comment: if I understood you correctly: you just want to print lines between `motd` and `Customer` from all files listed in `index` file, right?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I have completely edited my original entry to competely simplify things since I couldn't delete it, but I will reiterate, the input and output do not matter at this point, which is why they weren't originally included.

Comment: "The formulation of a problem is often more essential than its solution which may be merely a matter of mathematical or experimental skill." - Albert Einstein

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need something like this:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR { ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next }
    FNR == 1 { found=0 }
    $2 == "motd" { found=1 }
    found
    $1 == "customer" { nextfile }
' myindex
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide testable sample input/output. The above uses GNU awk for `nextfile`, with other awks replace `nextfile` with `found=0; next`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to manipulate it to do anything else I need it to do.  Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose a different approach since `getline` use needs to be very precise...

```
$ awk '/motd/{p=1} /Customer/{p=0} p' $(awk '{print $0".info"}' index)

motd
good stuff 1
good stuff 1
motd
good stuff 2
good stuff 2
motd
good stuff 3
good stuff 3
```

prepare the file names as arguments to the main script.  I added 1/2/3 suffix to show that the data is coming from the corresponding file.

where

```
==> index <==
one
two
three

==> one.info <==
blah
blah
blah
motd
good stuff 1
good stuff 1
Customer
blah
blah
end

==> three.info <==
blah
blah
blah
motd
good stuff 3
good stuff 3
Customer
blah
blah
end

==> two.info <==
blah
blah
blah
motd
good stuff 2
good stuff 2
Customer
blah
blah
```

Comment: I need to do this in a specific way, since this is a smaller part of a larger script.  I've left out those details for the sake of brevity, and I've edited out the requested details because I think that led down the rabbithole to a result I didn't require.

This is only about opening a file and reading the contents, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

> to print lines between `motd` and `Customer` from all files listed in
>   `index` file

***cat*** + ***sed*** pipeline:

```
cat index | xargs -I {} sed -n '/^motd$/,/^Customer$/{/^motd$/d; /^Customer$/d;p}' {}".information"
```

The above will output the needed lines excluding *pattern* lines